# Ok to repost code after incorporating suggestions?

Tags: discussion, site-policy

If I've had a piece of code reviewed here, what's the consensus about posting the update for another review?  Also, assuming it's ok, should it be an edit to the existing question, or a new post?  (With a link back to the original? )

Comment: That's quite literally exactly how follow-up questions work. The part about posting a new question I mean. An edit that invalidates existing answers is usually rolled back within seconds. See [what can/cannot I do after receiving answers?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for all the details.